# Select From Inner join - PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with a MYSQL query - I have 2 tables :

Table 1 (info) containing UID, first_name, last_name.
Table 2 (card) containing UID, pic .

What I am trying to do is get all results into an array:

```
WHERE UID IN '$ids' AND LEFT(last_name,1) = '$letter' ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC
```

I figured an `INNER JOIN` so my current code is:

```
("SELECT UID, first_name, last_name, pic FROM 
    (SELECT info.first_name,info.last_name,card.pic FROM info 
     INNER JOIN card ON info.UID=card.UID)
  WHERE LEFT(last_name,1) = '$letter' ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC")
```

This is producing the following error though:

'Every derived table must have it's own alias'.

Am I going about this the right way with inner join, and how do I give the derived table an alias? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b.UID, g.first_name, g.last_name, b.pic
from user_data.general_info g
inner join user_data.Bcards b on g.UID = b.UID
where LEFT(g.last_name, 1) = '$letter'
order by g.last_name, g.first_name asc
```

Comment: Great stuff, Thank you very much. Apologies for the inconsistent table/DB names. But thanks for the solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The inner query should be named.

```
    SELECT users.UID, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.pic FROM 
    (SELECT info.first_name,info.last_name,card.pic FROM user_data.general_info 
    INNER JOIN user_data.Bcards ON general_info.UID=Bcards.UID) users
    WHERE LEFT(users.last_name,1) = '$letter' ORDER BY users.last_name, users.first_name ASC
```